# How to get data form MySQL by dates in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have an app that I'm building using Django and I want to filter the data by dates. Basicaly, I used the raw sql query for this one. Is there any one that can help me?

Here's what I've one so far :

**views.py**

```
def getConnection():
    host = config['oof_ord']['host']
    port = config['oof_ord']['port']
    database = config['oof_ord']['database']
    password = config['oof_ord']['password']
    user = config['oof_ord']['user']
    try:
        connection = MySQLdb.connect(host=host, user=user, password=password, database=database)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        print("Connection to" + f'{connection}' + "successfully")
        return cursor
        
    except:
        return False

def getDate(request):

    weight_date = None

    if request.GET.get('weight_date') != None and request.GET.get('weight_date') != "":
        weight_date = request.GET.get('weight_date')
    else:
        weight_date = request.session.get('weight_date')

    return weight_date

def filler_weight(request):
    template_name = 'oof_ord/fill_weight.html'
    cursor = getConnection()
    date = getDate(request)
    try:
        query = "SELECT * FROM fill_weight where weight_date = '{rundate}' ".format(rundate = getDate(request))
        cursor.execute(query)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        
        print(rows[1][5])
        for row in rows:
            print(row)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
    return render(request, template_name, {"rows" : rows})
```

My code is working if I am going to show all the data in my MySQL but what if I want to filter data by it's specific dates and show it in my template ?

BTW, I get an error running this:

```
mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1525, "Incorrect DATE value: 'None'")
```

Comment: youe function get_date doesn't return a date it is empyt, so you should debug that

Comment: @nbk is there anyway that i can do like, after i pick date in my templates, it will show the data ?

Comment: has date = getDate(request)  a value, then use that, instead of calling the function again. further mysql expects date in yyyy-mm-dd format, so if the variable date has a value you should format it